# I get an error when running "git push heroku master"

Tags: javascript, heroku

After following the official heroku instructions on how to deploy an application, I have run "git push heroku master" but i get the following error:

```
To https://git.heroku.com/miguelangelparedes.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/miguelangelparedes.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Strangely, after i run "git pull", it says that everything is up to date, and when i push again, i get the same error. Would be nice if someone helped

Answer (score 1):

- Run `git pull` first and then try the push again.
- If you are the only person using this repository, and you are ABSOLUTELY sure that you version is correct, you can also `git push -f`, but this will OVERWRITE the server's version, so you have to be very careful.

Comment: @azidikk, please accept and upvote my answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku apps only run off of the master branch of the app repository (local to Heroku). If you want to deploy a branch to Heroku which isn't the master branch of your local repo, then you need to specify it
Try git push my-branch-name:master !
You'll likely need to add the -f flag to force push.